# How to get access token using PHP?

Tags: php, api, access-token, json

First of all I am authorizing my app at say, `/oauth/authorize/`. Then I am exchanging the authorization token for an access token at `/oauth/access_token/`. After successful exchange, I get an access token in json format on this page: `/oauth/access_token/?code=CODE&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL`.

Format:

```
{"access_token": "ACCESS_TOKEN", "token_type": "simple"}
```

I want to save/get this access token locally. How do I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert the JSON result into PHP variable:

```
$result = json_decode($returnedJSON);
var_dump($result);
```

Your `access_token` is retrieved by using this code:

```
echo $result->access_token;
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I retrieve the JSON result from the page? I can use file_get_contents, but after successful exchange the browser redirects to `/oauth/access_token/?code=CODE&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL`. @ariefbayu

Comment: well... you asked the wrong question. In this case, you want to know how to access OAuth API. Please google "PHP Oauth client"